# How do i make it so the background image loads as a "whole" rather than in sections and in black and white then colour?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using html, css, php and wordpress.

Currently I'm using a background image that is **1.8 mb**.
The website loads pretty well (under 2 seconds).

However during the load of the website, the background image is the last thing to load,
and loads in parts.

e.g. you see half of the background image in black and white, then the next half which is the final image.

My question is

**How do i make it so the background image loads as a "whole" rather than in sections and in black and white then colour?**

also **Is the image size too big?**

and extra question **How do i debug this in chrome dev tools?** i.e. how can i see whether or not the image is too big in chrome dev tools.
I tried recording the load in "performance" and the only information i got back, was that it took the image 1.5's out of the 2's to load.

Comment: Don't add the element to DOM initially: imgEl.decode().then(() => /* set image now */)

Comment: *How do i make it so the background image loads as a "whole" ?* Make it about 10 times smaller than it is (literally). It is HUGE, that's bigger than most of my homepages are in their entirety, including all images, css, js and everything else. That's why its taking so long to load.